# trouble in starting service when click a button

Tags: android, service

I have following piece of code in my application:

> .... tb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Auto-generated method stub
    startService(Intent this.Main);
}
});
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "yessssss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 //and do something//

}
```

and I want to start service when user click on "tb1" button,

I have tried:

> startService(new Intent(this, Main.class));

and

> startService(Main.class);

but none of them started service, what should i do ?

Comment: Give full path of `Service` in Manifest including package name.

Comment: what? you means instead of service i use Tab activity? i don't get it.

Comment: @hotveryspicy I did, ST like this '<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.black.service.Main" />' but it still dose not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code as for starting Service on Button Click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Current_Activity.this, Main.class);
startService(intent);
```

and make sure you have registered you service in Manifast.xml as:

```
<service
    android:name=".Main"/>
```

Comment: it still didnot started service.

Comment: it didn't worked. I may add this that my Current_Activity is same as Main.class, I mean I edited your code like this **Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main.class);**

Comment: not you can try  ` Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class); ` intead of  `Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main.class);` and what is your service name?

Comment: my service name is Main, and i'am using "bt1" button in same service, i mean i want to start service, with a button which is inside a service.

Comment: @Reza_Rg : then use  `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);startService(intent);` for starting service

Comment: ok change `Toast.makeText(context, "yessssss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` to `Toast.makeText(Main.class, "yessssss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Nope, didn't worked again, shouldn't I call startService(intent) from an Activity, out of Serivce?

Comment: call startService(intent) from Activity

Comment: Oh, That would be kind of you, Should I zip my whole code and send it to your mail? or just relevant codes?

Comment: sorry i didn't copy your mail, can you say it again ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
startService(myIntent);
```

Also add your service to your manifest

```
<service android:name="packagename.Main"></service>
```

Comment: it didn't worked. I may add this that my Current_Activity is same as Main.class, I mean I edited your code like this Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main.class);

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
startService(myIntent);
```

is no compiling
Remove arguments to match 'Intent()' is appearing with X mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
startService(myIntent);
```

is not compiling. Remove arguments to match `Intent()` is appearing with X mark.

A small change will work.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class); //is working both
startService(myIntent); and stopService(myIntent); // also working.
```